# Android CardView with a custom shadow color

Tags: android, shadow, android-cardview

Is it possible to change the color of the shadow around the CardView? Mainly used to mark selected the card **as it were lighted on**?

Should be valid on L and pre-L devices.

Comment: Still i am finding the solution for this. Pls let me know if you have.

Comment: @Maulikpatel I think I found a project on Github but I do not remember the name. What have you found?

Comment: It should be this one: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon: in the description it says "CardView with real shadows and rounded corners" but I did not tried out.

Comment: 9-patch image worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

`CardView` shadow colors are defined in the resources of the CardView library. You can override them by redefining the resource value in your own project but you can not change them dynamically by code.

**Edit:** overriding the resource value only affects pre-Lollipop devices. On Lollipop and above, `CardView` always uses the native shadow implementation whose color cannot be changed.

Comment: Changing by overriding is more than enough, but you mean to override these values? - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/frameworks/support/v7/cardview/res/values/colors.xml?av=f - In my color.xml I put my custom `<color name="cardview_shadow_start_color">#37000000</color>` and `<color name="cardview_shadow_end_color">#03000000</color>` - Is the system take them **automatically**?

Comment: Yes it's these values, they will apply to all your CardViews. I believe you also need to set useCompatPadding to true to be able to see the color on newer Android versions as well.

Comment: I tried now but it doesn't work. The resource comes from `android.support.v7.cardview.R.color.cardview_shadow_start_color` how it should take mine from my color.xml? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I correct myself, it works only on pre-L, but useCompatPadding is set true. Could you provide an example for L?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that setting "useCompatPadding" would make CardView use the pre-L implementation which uses the colors from the resources but it's not the case. On L CardView uses the native shadow and the native shadow color can't be customized. Your best option is probably to create a custom 9-patch image with built-in padding representing your custom colored shadow and use it as a background for a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Check [my modification](https://github.com/nvl2val/CardView/tree/master).

---

Here's a workaround:

Copy [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/cardview?autodive=0%2F) of `CardView`. Then create your own Android Library Module and use this module instead of support library. After these, **comment or remove code in CardView like below**:

```
static {
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
//            IMPL = new CardViewApi21Impl();
//        } else
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            IMPL = new CardViewApi17Impl();
        } else {
            IMPL = new CardViewBaseImpl();
        }
        IMPL.initStatic();
    }
```

That is, you will use compat-version `CardViewApi17Impl` even when api is 21 or higher. Then, you can define your own `cardview_shadow_start_color` and `cardview_shadow_end_color` to override those in class `RoundRectDrawableWithShadow`. Furthermore, you can make that more customizable.

Hope can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a small trick. One CardView is put behind another one. Both are the same, difference is `card_view:cardElevation="10dp"` for background one, and   `card_view:cardElevation="2dp"` for faced one. The subtraction of elevation provides how long is your shadow, and color of the second CardView gonna be color of the shadow for first one.

Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view_click_basement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorNewGreen"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view_click"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this :-

android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/"
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/"